# Unable to publish Microsoft project on PWA

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-project, project-online, pwa

I have created a Microsoft project on my local PC and trying to publish it on SharePoint PWA. If I create a project with normal/simple project template then there is an option foto publish it on SharePoint But When I create a project with any other project template the publish option is faded out.

Comment: what do you mean with  normal/simple project template  ? are you mean enterprise project ttype (EPT) ? or project site template  ?

Comment: I mean the Microsoft project professional templates.  The Microsoft project ask you when you create new file in it. There are options such as blank project,  software development etc. Then pre-existing entries are already created in it.

Comment: Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question ,

- You opened Microsoft Project > connect to server select the blank project template and in this case, you can find the Publish button.
- But if you have selected another template like commercial ...etc , you can't find the Publish button.

> This is because The selected templated is not saved to project server

So if you need to use another template you should first publish it to project server as **EnterPrise template** by doing the following :

- Open Microsoft Project.
- At login > at Profile > select the URL of Project Server, not computer.
- Now Select your favorite template like software development.
- From File Menu > click Save as.
- In Save > in type > select **template**.

[image]

- Now close , and open Microsoft Project again, and select from `Enterprise tab` your project template that you have already saved.

[image]

- Now you will see the publish button activated.